# Melding commands with mastered abilities

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep, kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

Let's say I have a Firaga with a Fire Boost ability, all maxed out, and I want to meld this Firaga with an Aerora to make Fission Firaga. Even though I have Firaga maxed out and Fire Boost is now an equippable ability, would I lose Fire Boost from my abilities menu once I meld these to make Fission Firaga?

I'm assuming no because it's already learned and mastered, but I just wanted to make sure before I go ham on the melding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you will not lose it. Once an ability has been mastered, it cannot be lost by melding, selling, or unequiping your abilities. When you have maxed out an ability, you should get a dialog popup explaining that the ability is now a permanent ability when you visit your "Edit Deck" page.

If you would like to turn an ability off, however, you can do so manually through the Ability menu